# Menu with inset transparent triangle

Tags: css

I'm trying to style a menu with an ***inset*** transparent triangle for each category. The html is like this:

```
<li class="level0 nav-1 level-top first">
<a class="level-top" href="http://shop.de/kinderzimmer">
<span>
<span class="navborder navborder-left"></span>
Kinderzimmer
<span class="navborder navborder-right"></span>
</span>
</a>
</li>
...
```

... but I can add/remove spans/classes etc. if needed.

My first attempt was this css:

```
#nav li.level0 a.level-top span {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    }
#nav li.level0 a.level-top span:after {
    content: "";
    left: 50%; /* center triangle */
    margin-left: -20px; /* center triangle */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
    border-right: 20px solid red;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    }   
#nav li.level0 a.level-top span span.navborder-left:after {
    border-bottom: 20px solid green;
    }
#nav li.level0 a.level-top span span.navborder-right:after {
    border-bottom: 20px solid blue;
    }
```

(The colors are just for debugging, the should be matching the nav background when finished.)

The result isn't as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/9brsR/6/

The borders from span.navborder-left and span.navborder-right have gaps to the centered triangle element.

Anyone has a clue how to fix the css to have something like this: http://puu.sh/7jMEe.png ?

Comment: I've share a working Demo. did this work for you?

Comment: I've updateded the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9brsR/8/
This shows that the main part is working (the background is grey), but I can't fill the **gaps** properly with the (border-color) red with that css and / or html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is little complicated but a few pseudo-elements will manage it.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LawCb)

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:15px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  font-size:0;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:1rem;
  color:white;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

li:before,
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:100%;
  width:calc(50% - 12px); /* allows to width of triangle*/
  height:12px;
  background-color: red;
}

li:before{
  left:0;
}

li:after {
  right:0;
}

a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  z-index:-1; /* hide behind link */
  border:12px solid red;
  top:100%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%); /* center the pseudo element and only show bottom half*/
}

a.current:before {
    border-bottom-color:transparent; /* our triangle */
}
```

**Browser support limited due to `calc` (IE9+) and pseudo-elements.**

Comment: Great answer, as margin will do the trick instead of transform:translate, this will make it IE8+, right?

a:before {
  ... 
  margin-top: -12px;
  margin-left: -12px;
}

Comment: @nooji. Yeah, margin would be the fallback but it's one more value to update so it's less flexible. IE8 support isn't perfect for pseudo elements but it is there (sort of).

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the triangle effect on mouse over by giving this property. Here is the Working Demo. http://jsbin.com/tevoliva/2/

-----------CSS Code---------------

```
ul{list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0;  background-color:#ef8913; }
ul li {display:inline-block; padding:15px; position:relative;}
ul li a{color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;}
li.active:after,
li:hover::after { 
    content: ' '; 
    display: block; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    z-index: 99; 
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
border-right: 12px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 12px solid white; 
}
```

-----HTML Code-------

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
<li class="triangle"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think he wants to have a transparent triangle not white.

Comment: Many thanks for the highly detailed fiddle, but I'm looking for a css that gives me an inset transparent triangle.

Comment: @KheemaPandey But this would show just the background of the div (or border color, im´n my case), right?

Comment: why you want to use transparent image? Is the `background-color` change dynamically in your app or in website? if no then you can keep the `background color` and the `bottom color` same. this way there will no dependency on image

Comment: @KheemaPandey You mean a transparent triangle? As this is part of a sticky navigation, it will only work that way.